# p:grid not finding css classes

Tags: css, primefaces

I am struggling with PrimeFaces css grid, I am using version 5.3 and can't get it working. Somehow the classes `ui-g`, `ui-g1`, etc. do not exist/work.

The [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml) to PrimeFaces css grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

My problem was that I used the classes `ui-g`, `ui-g-1`, etc. These are used in the examples on [primefaces.org](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml). While these classes not existed in version 5.3.

**Solution**

I switched these classes to the older ones: `ui-grid`, `ui-grid-col-1`, etc.